# Download vignettes (Rmd) from R package on GitHub?

Tags: r, github, devtools, r-package

I'm trying to install an R package from a private repository on `GitHub`. Package objects, such as `data` and `functions`, are downloaded as they should, but I'm missing the `vignettes`, i.e. the `.Rmd` that is located in the `/vignettes` folder of the package.

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("person_name/repo_name", build_vignettes = TRUE, auth_token =  "xxx")
```

My goal is to be able to download both `functions`, `data` and the `.Rmd` from the package using `install_github()`.

Ideally, the `functions` and `data` from the package would be in the RStudio memory (which works fine), while the `.Rmd` file should be downloaded locally to the directory I'm in when I download the package.

The purpose is to make it easy for a user to re-run the analysis (the `.Rmd`) with the included `data` and `functions`.

Is this possible or have I misunderstood the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vignettes are not stored in the local working directory. They are stored in the package bundle itself. You typically access them using

```
vignette("topicname", package="packagename")
```

If you want to get the path to that RMD file (assuming the source file is a markdown file which is not the case for all packages), you can write a little helper

```
get_vignette_source_path <- function(...) {
   v <- vignette(...)
   file.path(v$Dir, v$File)
}
```

For example with the `dplyr` "colwise" help

```
get_vignette_source_path("colwise", package="dplyr")
```

You could also have it copy the file to your working directory

```
file.copy(get_vignette_source_path("colwise", package="dplyr"), ".")
```

You could include a function in your package to do this if you like. you can also actuyally open an edit window for the source file itself with

```
edit(vignette("colwise", package="dplyr"))
```

and then the user could save that value where they like.

Comment: are vignettes part of the package bundle and therefore always downloaded and installed (but not built locally by default)?

Comment: @the-mad-statter Yes they are always part of the package bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! This helps a ton.